# Expanding and covering boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking forward to find a jQuery code that allows me to have the following behaviour (in the pictures). So I have a grid as shown below and if someone clicks on the red area (a DIV), that div will cover (go over the top) the boxes around it (two boxes from right or left side, one underneath or at the top)
And if he clicks again, the div goes back to its normal position and size
I can't figure out how do I achieve this? I would appreciate if someone can help please.

Stage 1:
http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/461/stage1.jpg

[image]

Stage 2:
http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/9601/stage2n.jpg

[image]

Comment: If you already have the HTML foundation, please put it on jsFiddle.

Comment: So hovering changes the box to red?

Comment: No red box is only an example, I was referring what will happen if you click that one only, I don't have the HTML for it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took me longer than I would care to admit:

http://jsfiddle.net/d4DZd/

The trick is to clone the element and grow that one instead of the original so that the elements keep their position.

Comment: Thank you this works great, how if I want to click on the box the is positioned at the bottom row using the same code?

Comment: Just add the click listener to it too. You have a pretty good example to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/kbPqU/

```
$(".box-spec").click(function() {
    var cover_width = 3,cover_height = 3;
    $("body").prepend('<div class="box-spec" style="width:' + ((128 + 10) * cover_width) + 'px;height:' + ((128 + 10) * cover_height) + 'px"></div>');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but the box in red should be similar to other ones and it uses the similar html code. Also how if user clicks on another box, for example the one at the right side-below. That one should covers te ones next to it as well.